# Как выводить обьекты класса из вектора?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "main.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Human
{
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string day;
    string month;
    string year;
public:
    Human(string m_name = "unknown", string m_surname = "unwknown", string m_day = "0", string m_month = "0", string m_year = "0" )
        :name(m_name), surname(m_surname), day(m_day), month(m_month), year(m_year){}
    struct Class {
        Class() { all.push_back(this); }
        static std::vector<Class*> all;
    };
    void getInformation_aboutPeople()
    {
        cout << name << " " << surname << endl;
        cout <<"Birhday: "<< day << "." << month << "." << year << endl;
    }
    void giveInofrmation_aboutPeople()
    {
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Surname: ";
        cin >> surname;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Day: ";
        cin >> day;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Month: ";
        cin >> month;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Year: ";
        cin >> year;
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

```
#include "Human.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    vector<Human> bd;
    vector <Human>::iterator iter;
    while (true)
    {
        int a;
        cout << "Add in database. (1)" << endl;
        cout << "See a database. (2)" << endl;
        cout << "Delete all in database. (3)" << endl;
        cout << "Delete last in database. (4)" << endl;
        cout << "Turn off. (5)" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 1)
        {
            Human man;
            man.giveInofrmation_aboutPeople();
            man.getInformation_aboutPeople();
            bd.push_back(Human(man));
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            for (iter = bd.begin(); iter != bd.end(); ++iter)
            {
                cout << *iter << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (a == 3)
        {
            bd.clear();
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (a == 4)
        {
            bd.pop_back();
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (a == 5)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

ошибка следующая:
отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам на 29 строке в основном файле

Comment: Пишите свой оператор вывода, как же иначе?

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const class_name& obj) {
    /* Вывод поэлементно */
    return os;
}
```

Так определяется оператор вывода для Вашего класса:

```cpp
class Human {

...

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Human& hum) {
        /* Здесь Вы выводите своего Human в консоль по одному его полю, например */
        os << "Name: " << hum.name << ", surname: " << hum.surname << ".\n"
           << "Birthday: " << hum.day << '.' << hum.month << '.' << hum.year << ".\n";
        
        return os;
    }

...

};
```